# MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage has null path

Tags: android, mediastore

Code:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long longParam) {
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    mImageAdapter.getItem(position));
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    b, "Photo", null);
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Photo: Share Photo To...")
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        }
    });
```

The files of the photos are stored as Jpeg files in the raw resource folder which are retrieved by the imageadapter.

path seems to be null and I can't figure out why this could be. I'm getting this issue only on KitKat devices so far. Any ideas what could have gone wrong and how I would go about fixing it? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: check  mImageAdapter.getItem(position) gives valid drawable image

Comment: Yes, it returns the correct resource id which is the required parameter where I put it :)

Comment: try to set that bitmap b in dummy image view.

Comment: "I'm getting this issue only on KitKat devices so far"....it works on all other OS versions..